# Maven: Do you have to declare plugins in the POM to use them

Tags: maven

If I don't include a plugin declaration in a POM, can I still use the plugin? Are these elements only there to override default behavior. If so what is the default behavior?

How does a project know about default plugins if it doesn't declare them explicitly? The documentation expresses that you must at least declare the plugin to inherit from a parent's PluginManagememt element. Are there other ways to inherit default plugin behavior?

Comment: Plugins and projects aren't really that coupled, the only reason you'd declare them in the POM would be to configure their behavior in the first place...

Comment: Agreed. While it's possible to call plugins from the command line, you normally need to POM to configure their behaviour (and location if they're not pulled from Maven Central). Some plugins (like Sonar for example) are configured completely using properties. This is the exception rather than the rule

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can!**

Remember Maven philosophy, convention over configuration. You don't need to configure everything as long as you fit into convention.

Default configuration is doing really much for you.

Experiment

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=test -DartifactId=test
cd test
mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=effective-pom.xml
```

Compare `pom.xml` with `effective-pom.xml` and see what Maven does for you out of the box.

Examples done using Maven 3.